# My Arduino pulse counter is counting too many pulses, why is this?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to count pulse but the results are showing too large numbers.  There are even negative numbers.

I'm using a Hall sensor for input. When the Hall sensor detects the magnet, the pulse state is High(1), and when magnet goes away the pulse state is Low(0). So if 000001111100000011111100000 the pulse is two.

I'd like to count the number of pulses in 1 second.

Below is my coding sketch. Is there a problem with it?

```
volatile int cnt=0;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), rpm, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(cnt);
  cnt=0;
  delay(1000);
}

void rpm() {
  cnt++;
}
```

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service. As such, this is off-topic for the site and is likely to be closed. This is detailed clearly for you in the site tour. You can choose to delete it yourself before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Again, welcome.

Comment: I think it's a valid question, just not worded appropriately for the site. I tried to fix it up.

Comment: @Drew, it's not a valid question within the guidelines of the site. Please see my comment.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code. Maybe your Hall output has high frequency oscillation or it's picking up switching regulator noise.

Make sure there is a common ground and the signal level is appropriate.

[image]

With 100Hz 0/5V 50% duty cycle input from a signal generator (Nano clone).

Answer (score 2):

This might be a hardware issue with counting a single edge multiple times, but that's not the only issue.

Assuming you are running this code on an 8-bit AVR MCU, it's pretty clear that you are using the count variable dangerously.

Integers are 16 bit variables on an AVR and it can only work with 8-bit quantities at a time so it might be that the interrupt that increases the variable happens in the middle of reading the variable for printing so it prints false results and it may happen while writing the variable to zero so it may not get zeroed properly.

Oh and as the variable is a signed 16-bit integer, it can only count up to 32767 interrupts per second before being interpreted as negative number counting from -32768 upwards back to 0.